# How to embed Google Analytics in Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, google-analytics

I'm fairly new to Salesforce and Lightning Components, so please bear with me. I have a test Lightning Component named `ajAppComponent` and want to embed Google Analytics in the component.

First, I added https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-1 as a static resource named `GoogleAnalytics`. I've also added https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js as `analytics`.

In my `ajAppComponent.cmp` file, I've added the following line:

`<ltng:require scripts="{!'/resource/GoogleAnalytics'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.gaLoaded}" />`

I've also tried it loading the `analytics` static resource, but that didn't help either.

In my `ajAppComponentController.js` I have the `gaLoaded` function, which has:

```js
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1');
```

But neither show any activity in my Google Analytics homepage. I know it's loading the `gaLoaded` function as I've put in debugging code (console.log) and I see the resource loaded when I look in Google Dev Tools.

Am I missing a step somewhere? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you add a [CSP Trusted Site](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5), and/or a [Remote Site Setting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=configuring_remoteproxy.htm&type=5) for the googletagmanager.com and google-analytics.com domains?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing out the `send` step as mentioned here [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference).

> Sends a hit to Google Analytics. The fields that are sent are the
>   values specified in the ...fields parameters and fieldsObject, merged
>   with the fields currently stored on the tracker.

here is my sample code of `afterScriptLoaded`

```
afterScriptLoaded: function (component) {
        // store the name of the Analytics object
        window.GoogleAnalyticsObject = 'ga';
        // check whether the Analytics object is defined
        if (!('ga' in window)) {
            // define the Analytics object
            window.ga = function () {
                // add the tasks to the queue
                window.ga.q.push(arguments);
            };

            // create the queue
            window.ga.q = [];
        }
        // store the current timestamp
        window.ga.l = (new Date()).getTime();
        window.ga_debug = {
            trace: true
        };
        debugger;


        ga('create', trackingid, {
            'userId': userdata.name,
            'storage': 'none',
            'dimension3': userdata.name,
            'dimension4': userdata.accountName
        });
        ga('send', 'pageview');

    }
```

Comment: Which script do you run as a static resource? Also, would I replace "trackingid" with my own tracking ID? I added your code and when I go to Google Analytics "Real Time" I still don't see any activity. Thank you!